# Popcorn.js - How to make lower third plugin appear only on pause

Tags: popcornjs

I would like to make the plugin "lowerthird" appear only when the video is paused.
I.E listen to the pause event, and display the text from lower third plugin...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Popcorn events activate based on the time. So you would have to make an event, hide it using CSS, then make it visible on pause.